# Wordpress default user registration form shortcode

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode, wordpress-plugin-creation

I build a website in WordPress and want to show the default WordPress register form on a custom theme template.

```
<?php do_action('register_form'); ?>
```

Is there is any way to create a shortcode for default wp register form
Or
please help me how I create a field to upload a profile picture/photo from default register form

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Best easy way is using plugin. ACF that plugin can help you to add extra/custom fields in your default login page and that data you can fetch any where as your requirement easily. see the below links may be help you something.

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf_register_form/
https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/front-end-user-registration/
https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/frontend-user-registration-form/